# How to disable mouse gestures as a developer?

Tags: javascript, css, browser, mouse, gestures

I'm developing a web application and I noticed how irritating mouse gestures can be on it, so, is there a way to disable them (Firefox and Opera particularly)?

Edit: It seems there is some confusion. I'm developing a web based software that has an interface with such complex actions and tasks such as mouse selections, file drag and dropping, a desktop and a Windows Explorer -style filesystem. Whenever I try to select multiple virtual files and move them around, mouse gestures will apply and take me away from the software and navigate to the previous page or do something else nasty. My project is not a website, it's a web application -- mouse gestures are poison to this project.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "mouse gestures" ?

Comment: I think OP means http://www.opera.com/browser/tutorials/gestures/ https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/12

Comment: I don't know whether it could be done, but with my "web user" hat on I'll say that I hope not.  If a user has gone to the trouble of enabling mouse gestures, it probably means that they like using their browser that way.

Comment: @Pointy: he seems to be implying that the standard gestures cause unwanted side effects with **his application**. Nothing wrong with trying to prevent that, as long as it doesn't affect anything else.

Comment: Yes, Mouse Gestures that are part of Opera installation and can be added into Firefox and Chrome using extensions. Those that let you navigate away from the page and so forth with a movement of your mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say you're using a library, but this is a jQuery plugin to detect gestures: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jGesture

Looking at the source code, looks like it depends on measuring the action b/t mousdown and mouseup ... lotsa math.

And Mozilla offers some event handlers.. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Mouse_gesture_events but it has a big Non-standard stamped on it.

Answer (score 1):

the polite thing to do would be to inform users that to take full advantage of your site, they should disable mouse gestures temporarily.